# How to obtain a thread dump from Tomcat running as a Windows service

Tags: windows, tomcat

Installing Tomcat as a Windows service comes with a handy system tray tool to control it which provides this menu:

[image: Thread dump option]

However, everything I've been able to find suggests the "Thread Dump" option should not be on this menu because it will never work - Windows services have no console, so the dump written to stderr/stdout is lost. It does not appear in the `tomcat8-stdout.2023-08-16` or equivalent stderr log file.

Has anyone made this option work? It would be perfect for situations where tools like jstack are not available on production servers.